# DNS Leak when using OpenVPN in Raspberry Pi OS

Tags: raspbian, vpn, dns, pi-hole

I could never force OpenVPN to use the remote DNS provided by the vpn server in the latest Raspberry Pi OS (ubuntu has no problem in network manager by default). I've tried so many ways to fix the DNS leak in Raspberry OS following the tutorials online and nearly all suggested a public DNS such as 8.8.8.8 and 1.1.1.1 through settings in Router or .conf.  Even though I could force the DNS to 8.8.8.8 or 1.1.1.1 etc. it still leaks my country of origin because Google/etc. forwards the requests to a local DNS server with a local IP.

Comment: Hi there. This is really interesting news. But because Stack Exchange is a Question and Answer site, I would suggest editing your question. The post above here.. make it a question. And then answer your own question. This is perfectly valid. It has merit that in time a new solution may be found and that could become a very helpful answer along side yours. Thanks for sharing. I hope you find the time to edit your question. As by rules this may get closed or deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to share a relatively easy fix I discovered by chance - install Pihole. It fixed the leak by forcing the DNS the same as the external IP assigned by VPN provider.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.